# Create custom keyboard shortcut in Ubuntu 17.10 / 18.04

Tags: shortcut-keys

In previous versions of Ubuntu I could create custom keyboard shortcut to run terminal commands, with something like `gksudo reboot` for example, and then assign that to something like <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>.

I can't find that option in Ubuntu 17.10 or Ubuntu 18.04 daily build.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6):

Follow the steps below.

1. Go to Settings -> Devices -> Keyboard.
2. Scroll to bottom, and click the "+" (plus) sign.
3. Enter the command and assign a shortcut key.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Do I need to reboot?

Comment: Like @CostaMichailidis said - I do this and the commands just don't work. I have tried to log-out, also reboot, nothing brings them to live. What is needed to activate the newly created custom shortcuts?

Answer (score 2):

For those who can't manage to find the adequate Settings (Ubuntu 18.04 maybe?), run in a terminal:

`gnome-control-center`

...then follow the procedure that @opensas mentioned:

1. Go to Settings -> Devices -> Keyboard.
2. Scroll to bottom, and click the "+" (plus) sign.
3. Enter the command and assign a shortcut key.

Comment: I do this and the commands just don't work. I have tried to log-out, also reboot, nothing brings them to live. What is needed to activate the newly created custom shortcuts?