# Keyboard shortcut to settings in ubuntu 17.10/18.04?

Tags: 18.04, 17.10

Anyone know whether ubuntu 17.10/18.04 has a preset keyboard shortcut to to settings?

Comment: Just go to Settings, Keyboard and type `settings` to search for Settings shortcuts.

Comment: Don't think there is one to launch Settings, but you can easily set one manually. Follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1019262/480481) and set a shortcut for the command `gnome-control-center`.

Comment: I ended up searching for `keyboard` in the dash.  This allows you to click on `keyboard` under settings and the dialog allows the changing of the shortcut.  I ended up using `crtl shift s`.

Comment: I'd argue that this is not a duplicate on the basis that it's asking for a "preset".  I arrived here because I have a machine that, on install, doesn't have an accessible primary display, so I was looking for a way to bring up the settings dialog without a mouse! :-)